# Is there a way to get the Pub/Sub -> Dataflow -> BigQuery template to cope with multiple records per message?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I've got some applications publishing messages to Pub/Sub, and each message will contain one or more events. E.g.

```
{
  ...pub/sub headers...
  "data": "{\"event\":\"event1\",\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n{\"event\":\"event2\",\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n{\"event\":\"event3\",\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"
}
```

And I'd like to end up with data in BigQuery like:

```
event  | key1   | key2
event1 | value1 | value2
event2 | value1 | value2
event3 | value1 | value2
```

I need to get these events stored in BigQuery, and the available template looks like it should be a great fit. However, I'm getting stuck on the "more" events part of the problem.

I've got a very simple Javascript UDF that's doing a little bit of preprocessing on the inbound messages, but I can't for the life of me figure out what, if any, format will make the rest of the Dataflow job happy with the fact that the output of that UDF represents multiple records for saving into BigQuery.

Is what I'm attempting even possible without creating a custom Dataflow job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PubSub to Bigquery dataflow template, it takes one entry and write 1 corresponding row. You can't fan out the number of rows (I didn't try, but in the code, that seems not possible).

You can either build a custom Dataflow (you can start from the [existing template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/fe9b46839b0260e8cf56f16763ba1c528c29a0a1/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java).

Or, and it's ma preferred way, you can post process the dataflow pipeline with a bigquery query.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I feared as much. I appreciate the feedback!